# How to zoom in a histogram in seaborn/matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I produced a histogram which looks something like this:

[image]

Code that I used to produce this plot:

```
sns.countplot(table.column_name)
```

As you can notice, the entire histogram gets clustered at the left end due to uneven distribution of data.

How do I zoom in at the left end?

One way that I tried and it gave me a marginally better result was :

```
plt.xlim(0,25)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What doesn't work for you with `plt.xlim(0,25)`?

Comment: Did you tried `range` as a parameter in `plt.hits()`. For example: `plt.hist(..., ..., range(0, 25)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : End up losing data for all x > 25. Just checking if there is a better way

Comment: You're going to end up losing data one way or another if you zoom in, no?

Comment: what do you mean by "a better way"? Why are you not satisfied with that? If you just want to zoom the plot, this is the way to do it. If you want to change the intervals on which data are calculated, you need to use range as indicated above (even if there are 2 syntax errors in the comment).

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the data would be better viewed on a logarithmic scale. On your matplotlib plot axis, `ax`, use:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```