# How to zoom in on a plot using seaborn?

Tags: seaborn

`fig=plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(18,14)
    ax1 = sb.scatterplot(x=tcr_tvr_hvr.Median_tcr, y=tcr_tvr_hvr.Median_tvr,
    hue=tcr_tvr_hvr.US_Broad_Asset_Class).set(title = 'Asset Class Distribution BY Median Trade Cancel
    Ratio VS Median Trade Volume Ratio')`

Need to zoom in on the plot .

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zoom in a histogram in seaborn/matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949841/how-to-zoom-in-a-histogram-in-seaborn-matplotlib)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com//questions/52160719/is-it-possible-to-do-a-zoom-inset-using-seaborn, and a few others i noticed. Can only raise one duplciate flag though. Just search "seaborn zoom", many many hits here and in google

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
plt.gca().set_xlim([0, 100])
plt.gca().set_ylim([0, 100])
```